# Mars twilight photos

Tags: mars, curiosity, imaging

From the file:[PIA19401-MarsCuriosityRover-GaleCrater-Sunset-Animation-20150415.gif](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PIA19401-MarsCuriosityRover-GaleCrater-Sunset-Animation-20150415.gif)

Of the four images below from the gif, one of them depicts twilight.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Were there anymore twilight images in this sequence that were released to the public?

Comment: Images like these *might* qualify but I'm not qualified to judge: [Why is this “grainy footage” of a Martian (sky) from Curiosity so grainy? Cloud snaps by Opportunity look great!](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20787/12102)

Comment: Look for sol 956 on the raw images site: https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/multimedia/raw-images/

Comment: @Cornelisinspace That link looks like it will be a great resource.

Comment: To answer "how long does twilight last on Mars?" you might enjoy the various tables from about page 16 onwards in:  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19890018252.pdf

Comment: See your thread over there: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34418/at-mars-equator-how-long-does-twilight-last

Answer (score 3):

[image: twilight]
Sunset on sol 956, april 14, 2015

**Almost twilight !**

Comment: Really great image, but I'm trying to find out how long twilight lasts on Mars.  I was hoping if there is a full sequence of images from sunset until it was dark I could calculate it.

Comment: @Bob516 Thank you for the blue sunset ! It's possible to look for the term "twilight" on the NASA mission update site. https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/mission-updates/ With the found sols there, you can look for raw images.